# Label in Textbox if value filled (on AJAX Submit or in general)

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have build a simple modal which contains the form.
After submitting the content of this modal is reloaded by the Ajax response. But in general this is problem occurs if the value of a field is filled out, too. So doesn't matter if I use Ajax or not.

After reloading this page with value attribute set It looks like the one which is empty before you clicked on it. If you click on a field then the label is moving up.

This is the form in the default empty state.

```
<form name="" method="post" action="/web/app_dev.php/partner/0/edit">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <nav class="blue">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <div class="left col s12 m5 l5">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add partner</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="model-email-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" maxlength="255" class="validate" /><label for="firstName">Vorname</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" maxlength="255" class="validate" /><label for="lastName">Nachname</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" maxlength="254" pattern=".{2,}" class="validate" /><label for="email" class="required">E-Mail Adresse</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="company" name="company" maxlength="255" class="validate" /><label for="company">Firma</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="street" name="street" maxlength="255" class="validate" /><label for="street">Straße</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="houseNumber" name="houseNumber" maxlength="255" class="validate" /><label for="houseNumber">Hausnummer</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" maxlength="255" class="validate" /><label for="zipCode">PLZ</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="city" name="city" maxlength="255" class="validate" /><label for="city">Ort</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="radius" name="radius" class="validate" /><label for="radius">Radius</label></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-blue btn-flat modal-action">Speichern</button></div><input type="hidden" id="_token" name="_token" value="Y1e3fJNlUAyLs2bhz7cyTekAy4P2MGtGrojZ7YH924g" />
</form>
```

[image: Example before]

**And this is happens if I have value attribute filled.**

```
<form name="" method="post" action="/web/app_dev.php/partner/0/edit">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <nav class="blue">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <div class="left col s12 m5 l5">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add partner</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="model-email-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" maxlength="255" class="validate" value="this"><label for="firstName">Vorname</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" maxlength="255" class="validate" value="fields"><label for="lastName">Nachname</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" maxlength="254" pattern=".{2,}" class="validate" value="are-manually@filled.out"><label for="email" class="required">E-Mail Adresse</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="company" name="company" maxlength="255" class="validate"><label for="company">Firma</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="street" name="street" maxlength="255" class="validate"><label for="street">Straße</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="houseNumber" name="houseNumber" maxlength="255" class="validate"><label for="houseNumber">Hausnummer</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" maxlength="255" class="validate"><label for="zipCode">PLZ</label></div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="city" name="city" maxlength="255" class="validate"><label for="city">Ort</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3"><input type="text" id="radius" name="radius" class="validate"><label for="radius">Radius</label></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-blue btn-flat modal-action">Speichern</button></div><input type="hidden" id="_token" name="_token" value="Y1e3fJNlUAyLs2bhz7cyTekAy4P2MGtGrojZ7YH924g">
</form>
```

[image: Example how it looks with value filled]

Comment: You should be using the `placeholder` attribute on inputs, instead of positioning labels on top of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Sorry. I should read the documentations more...

http://materializecss.com/forms.html#first_name2

I must add the `active` class to the inputs...

Comment: So your problem is resolved ? Can you please mark answered ?